# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'firebase'

Tags: reactjs, firebase

### fire.js file

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyCAXvS25TnYA3qliFTP5vNUl4hU0Ilwv2U",
authDomain: "react-firebase-auth-signup.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "react-firebase-auth-signup",
storageBucket: "react-firebase-auth-signup.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "912198243014",
appId: "1:912198243014:web:bd683a011865825259fdc7"


}const fire= firebase.initialApp(firebaseConfig);
export default fire;
```

### App.js file

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import fire from './config/fire';
import Home from './Home';
import Logup from './Logup';
class App extends Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state={
  user:{}
}`}`
componentDidMount(){
this.authListener();
}authListener(){
  fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
    if(user){
      this.setState({user})
    }
    else{
      this.setState({user:null})
    }
  })

}


render(){
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    {this.state.user?(<Home/>):(<Logup/>)}
    console.log(firebase.default.auth)
  </div>
);


}
}

export default App;

## Error ##
```

---

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/config/fire.js 3:0-32

Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package D:\myprojects\firebase projects\Signin-signup-form\signin-up\node_modules\firebase (see exports field in D:\myprojects\firebase projects\Signin-signup-form\signin-up\node_modules\firebase\package.json)

Comment: You have a typo on your `fire.js`. Try changing `firebase.initialApp` to `firebase.initializeApp`

Comment: What are you using? Firebase v8 or v9?

Comment: firebase version : v9

Comment: I am try this changed firebase.initialApp to firebase.initializeApp. it showing same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure to get the latest firebase module:

```
npm i firebase@latest
```

For v9, use this code as follows:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = { 
// your-config 
};

const fire = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default fire;
```

To get the `auth`, use the code below:

```
const auth = getAuth(fire);
onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
  // Check for user status
});
```

For more information about using Firebase v9, you may check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

npm i firebase@latest

**and** import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';